# dynamically change stylesheet C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the style sheet of a group of controls on the selected index change of a dropdown.

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcPreview" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Text="Test1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Test2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<ajax:ComboBox ID="cmbTest" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AccessKey="f"  Width="325" Height="20"
AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False" ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText" style="margin-left:-3px;" TabIndex="3"> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Test1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Test2"></asp:ListItem>
</ajax:ComboBox><br />
<div class="gridmain">

<asp:GridView ID="grvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
ShowHeader="True" CssClass="tabledata" Width="100%" >
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="pointer"  />
<RowStyle CssClass="even pointer" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="headings" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I want to apply different stylesheet only to this placeholder and not to the entire page depending on the value selected in the dropdown.

I am using this in the code behind

```
                HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
                css.Href = "themes/" + theme + "/css/default.css";
                css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
                css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
                plcPreview.Controls.Add(css);
```

But the stylesheet gets applied to the entire page. I want it to be applied only to the placeholder and not to the entire page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply a stylesheet to only a section of the page. If you want to achieve that goal, your css file must have specific css selectors that only match the section you want to style and everything that's inside it.

for example, in your css you can have the following:

```
<asp:placeholder id="plcPreview" ...>
   <div class="c"
```

css:

```
#plcPreview
{
   color:black;
}

#a.c
{
    color:red;
}
```

And so on...

Anything else that's on the css file that matches the other elements outside the place holder will be matched and styled as well.

Answer (score 0):

Style sheets when loaded are visible to whole of the page, it seems that you are loading a style sheet and adding it to placeholder which will make it visible to all of the elements of DOM once the page is rendered.

The best approach I think is using JQuery [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), Give it a try.